# C# Why does "If (Tuple == Class1.Tuple)" not work, but "If (Tuple.Item1 == Class1.Tuple.Item1 && Tuple.Item2 == Class1.Tuple.Item2)" does?

Tags: c#, if-statement, tuples

I've been teaching myself C# over the last few months, mostly through trial/error and lots of google/stackoverflow searches, and I'm a tad confused as to whats happening/not happening here. My only previous coding experience came from Udacity's CS101 course about 3+ years ago, which involved some basic Python, most of which I had forgotten by the time I started C#.

```
class Class1
{
    public Tuple<int, int> StoredLoc = Tuple.Create(12, 6);
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Class1 Cls1 = new Class1();

    private bool CheckLocation(int x, int y) //x = 12, y = 6
    {
        Tuple<int, int> loc = Tuple.Create(x, y);
        //This Does Not work
        if (loc == Cls1.StoredLoc)
        {
            //Do Code
        }

        //This Does Work
        if (loc.Item1 == Cls1.StoredLoc.Item1 && loc.Item2 == Cls1.StoredLoc.Item2)
        {
            //Do code
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Why does `loc == Cls1.StoredLoc` not work?

Comment: You compare there reference. And this is not the same here. [Value Types and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Comment: Just a suggestions: consider using a `System.Windows.Point` or `System.Drawing.Point` (depending on what type of app you have) instead of a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tuple` doesn't overload `==` so it's comparing the references (and since `loc` and `Cls1.StoredLoc` are not the same object and do not share the same reference, it returns `false`)

But you can use: `loc.Equals(Cls1.StoredLoc)`, that should return true if both members are equal (in case of `int`, if its values are the same)

[Check it in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ooYxa5)

You can have more information about how the members are compared when using `Equals` in [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), specifically:

> The obj parameter is considered to be equal to the current instance under the following conditions:
>
> - It is a Tuple object.
> - Its two components are of the same types as the current instance.
> - Its two components are equal to those of the current instance. Equality is  determined by the default object equality comparer for each component.

Comment: Yeah, I was explaining the very basics... furthermore I'd more likely not use a `Tuple` when I want to define a *location*, which by the sample code it seems it's what the OP is aiming at, I was just answering the specific question :-)

Comment: @PhatWrat no need to, it's a fair comment. I've just added the link to the MSDN so he can investigate it further :-)